# Square root of normal positive operators over real Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

A bounded linear operator $A$ on a Hilbert space $H$ is called a positive operator if $\langle Ax, x\rangle \geq 0$ for all  $x$ in $H$. It is known that, if $A$ is a positive operator on a Hilbert space  $H$ over the complex field $\mathbb{C}$, then $A$ has unique positive square root.

My question is the following: 
Does a normal positive operator on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space over the real field $\mathbb{R}$ has a normal positive square root? If  exist, is it unique?

Comment: What is a normal positive operator? That sounds selfadjoint.

Comment: @TrialAndError  An operator $A$ is called normal, if it commutes with its adjoint operator.

Comment: House-keeping: The question is now answered on math overflow https://mathoverflow.net/questions/254385/square-root-of-normal-positive-operators-over-real-hilbert-spaces